# For a toss of fair die, if events are, A: {1,2}, B: {2,4,6}, and C: {4,5,6}, then A and B are independent but B and C are not. Why?

Tags: probability, independence

As far as I understood independence, A and B should not be independent since if either of them happens then we can tell something about the other one. But if they are independent then B and C should also be. From mathematical proof it is explainable, but I didn't understand the intuition behind it.

[image: The example is from “Elementary Bayesian Statistics” by Gordon Antelman, Chapter 2]

The example is from “Elementary Bayesian Statistics” by Gordon Antelman, Chapter 2

Text:

> For a fair die $U = (1,2,3,4,5,6)$. Let three events be defined as:
>
> - $A \equiv (1,2)$, so $P(A)=2/6$
> - $B \equiv (2,4,6)$, so $P(B)=3/6$, and
> - $C \equiv (4,5,6)$, so $P(A)=3/6$
>
> Then
>
> - $A \cap B = (2)$ and $P(A \cap B) = 1/6 = P(A)P(B) = (1/3)(1/2)$, so A
>   and B are independent.
> - $B \cap C = (4,6)$ and $P(B \cap C) = 2/6 \ne P(B)P(C) = (1/2)(1/2)$,
>   so B and C are not independent.

Comment: Rename the faces of the die from $1,2,3,4,5,6$ to $(1,0),(1,1),(2,0),(2,1),(3,0),(3,1),$ thereby identifying them with the Cartesian product $\{1,2,3\}\times\{0,1\}$ and notice the distribution is the product of the uniform distributions on these two sets. Writing the coordinates as $(x,y),$ $A$ is the event  $x=1$ while $B$ is the event $y=1,$ making their independence intuitively obvious. In some sense, all independent events occur in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other explanation why $\color{red}{A = \{1, 2\}} $ and $\color{blue}{B = \{2, 4, 6\}}$ are independent:

Someone rolled a die:

- The probability of the event $\color{red}A$ is $\color{red}{2\mkern-0.1ex/6}$, i.e. $\color{red}{1\mkern-0.1ex/3}$.
- Someone tells you that the result is an $\color{blue}{\text{even}}$ number (the event $\color{blue}B$).  *In spite of this new info* the probability of $\color{red}A$ is *still* $\color{red}{1\mkern-0.1ex/3}$
  ($\color{blue}2 \in \color{red}A$, but $\color{blue}{4} \notin \color{red}A$, $\color{blue}6 \notin \color{red}A$).

In the opposite way —

- The probability of event $\color{blue}B$ is $\color{blue}{3\mkern-0.1ex/6}$, .i.e. $\color{blue}{1\mkern-0.1ex/2}$.
- Someone tells you that the result is a number $\color{red}1$ or $\color{red}2$ (the event $\color{red}A$). *In spite of this new info* the probability of $\color{blue}B$ is *still* $\color{blue}{1\mkern-0.1ex/2}$
  ($\color{red}2 \in \color{blue}B$, but $\color{red}{1} \notin \color{blue}B$).

---

*Note:*

You may use the same scheme to see that the events $\color{blue}B$ and $\color{green}C$ are *not* independent.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. So what I understood is: if B happens then the probability of A will still be 1/3 because {2}/{2,4,6} and if A happens then also the probability of B will be same (1/2) because {2}/{1,2}. And in case of B and C, if B happens i.e. {2,4,6} the probability of C will be 2/3 because {4,6}/{2,4,6} and if C happens, the probability of B will also be 2/3 {4,6}/{4,5,6} in which case the probability of  C (1/2) and B (1/2) has changed respectively and that's why they are not independent. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @someUser, exactly, nothing to correct. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

You probably confuse *indepenent events* for *mutually exclusive events.*

> ... A and B should not be independent since if either of them happens then we can tell something about the other one.

It is not true. What does mean “something”? *The **probability** of “the other one” didn't change!*

The correct formulation should be

- “A and B **are** independent — if either of them happens, then it **doesn't change the probability** of the other”.

---

As I wrote, you are probably confused *mutually exclusiveness* (the empty intersection, distinctiveness) for the *independence* of two events.

But they are two independent things:

- the events $\{1\}$ and $\{2, 4, 6\}$ **are** mutually exclusive, but they are **not** independent,
- the events $\{2\}$ and $\{2, 4, 6\}$ are **neither** mutually exclusive, **nor** independent,
- the events $\{1, 2\}$ and $\{2, 4, 6\}$ are **not** mutually exclusive, but they **are** independent,
- the events $\emptyset$ and $\{2, 4, 6\}$ **are** mutually exclusive, and they **are** independent.

---

Independence can arise in two distinct ways:

- we *explicitly assume* that events are independent (e.g. rolling a die again), or
- we *derive* independence by verifying that it fulfills the formula $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$.

Generally, there is no way to “see” the independence (e.g. by looking in a Venn diagram).

By other words, if we may “see” the independence of two events, then they certainly fulfill the formula. But the opposite is not true — the formula is fulfilled, the independence is guaranteed, but there is not a visible reason, why.

The idea of independent events arises from the evident, noticable independence, but is not limited to it.

Comment: So how can A $\cap$ B and B $\cap$ C be explained in current scenario?

Comment: @someUser, don't try to “see” the independence by interpreting intersections of 2 events. Most teachers don't teach their student what I wrote in my answer — independence is sometime visible (and understandable), sometime not.